# Colored man pages but git --help is not in ZSH

Tags: git, shell, zsh, man

I have colored man pages according to:

```
alias man="TERMINFO=~/.terminfo/ LESS=C TERM=mostlike PAGER=less man"
```

so

```
man less
```

looks like

[image]

but git blame --help is uncolored

Comment: Voting to move to Super User, this is not a programming question.

Comment: and `man git-blame` is uncolored too?

Comment: no `man git-blame` is colored, I posted a revised pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `git help` does not execute your `man` alias, but the plain `man` command. Try setting `TERMINFO`, `LESS`, `TERM` and `PAGER` in the overall environment instead of inside the `man` alias.

Comment: Is there anyway to set the TERM variable just for man? This messes up all my other colors e.g. ls, vim, etc.

Comment: @dasickis: you could put `TERM=mostlike /usr/bin/man` in a script, say, `~/bin/man`.

Comment: groff uses hard-coded escape sequences for coloring manpages, so setting `TERM` is largely irrelvant.